# Construct matrix A with two given vectors, c,d where Col A = Nul A = Span {c,d}

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, random-matrices

Let **c** = $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\2 \\1 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}$ and let **d** =$\begin{bmatrix}1 \\0 \\0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$. Give an example of a matrix A with the property,

Span {**c**,**d**} = Nul A = Col A

So, I tried denoting A = [**v1 v2 v3 v4**] and solve the following equations:

A $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\2 \\1 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}$ = **v1** + 2 **v2** + **v3** + 2 **v4** = $0$ and

A $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\0 \\0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$ = **v1** + **v4** = $0$. Therefore **v1** = -**v4** , so **c** and **d** cannot be the first and fourth column,

since **c** and **d** are in Col A and thus in A.

So I found  A=
\begin{bmatrix}
a11 & 1 & 1 & a14 \\
a21 & 2 & 0 & a24 \\
a31 & 1 & 0 & a34 \\
a41 & 2 & 1 & a44
\end{bmatrix}

Or A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a11 & 1 & 1 & a14 \\
a21 & 0 & 2 & a24 \\
a31 & 0 & 1 & a34 \\
a41 & 1 & 2 & a44
\end{bmatrix}

However, I am stuck and I do not know how to proceed, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven’t exhausted the constraints imposed by $\operatorname{Span}\{\mathbf c,\mathbf d\}=\operatorname{Nul}A$ yet. For either of the possibilities for $A$ that you’ve worked out so far, the equations $A\mathbf c=\mathbf 0$ and $A\mathbf d=\mathbf 0$ give you a system of 8 homogeneous linear equations in 8 unknowns. Solve them and you’ll have $A$.